# creating an alias_attribute for a paperclip image in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm currently building an app which has a model `Post`.  I'm using the `paperclip` gem to upload images, and everything is going well.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :headerimage, styles: {banner => "400x300#"}
end
```

As you can see by my class above, if I were to get a `Post` object, I could get the banner image with the following in my view:

```
image = Post.first.headerimage(:banner)
```

#### Alias

However, in my app, it *must* have the image attribute `image` refer to the thumbnail image.  So, in my models class, I wrote

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :headerimage, styles: {banner => "400x300#"}
    alias_attribute :image, :headerimage
end
```

which allows me to get an image by calling the following:

`image = Post.first.image`

This is what I want - however, it gets the *original* image from paperclip, so it is equivalent to writing the following:

`image = Post.first.headerimage` instead of `image = Post.first.headerimage(:banner)`

How can I set up a proper alias_attribute to access the paperclip thumnail?  I can't seem to find an answer anywhere else, and I am unsure how paperclip is actually working.

I thought I might logically be able to do something like

`alias_attribute :image, :headerimage(:banner)`

but that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just try this - basically call the original with arguments since aliases won't take parameter but we know the fixed parameter to pass:

```
alias :image, :headerimage

def headerimage(name=nil)
  headerimage(name || :thumb)
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I feel silly for not knowing I could do that :)

Comment: nw, your question is quite useful I think honestly

Comment: Nice, this is what you need.

Comment: So, `alias` requires actual methods, not strings or symbols, and it doesn't allow a comma between them. Also, won't that `headerimage` method just go round in circles until the stack depth limit is reached and you get a crash? How did this work at all?